# SAS creating identifier

Tags: sas

I have a dataset with patient having multiple courses during a treatment phase.
Data set looks like:

```
C 1 1 0  
C 0 0 1  
C 1 1 0  
C 0 0 1
```

The first two rows: patient start at row1 and finishes at row2. This is the first course of patient C.

The second two rows: patient C again starts at row3 and finishes at row four.

How can I create an identifier for these two courses using the first and last statements in SAS.

Expected output should look like this;

```
C 1 1 0  23
C 0 0 1  23
C 1 1 0  24
C 0 0 1  24
C 1 1 1  25
```

The counts for one course should be the same and different from courses to courses within he same patient.
Thanks.

Comment: Search for data step with by groups. This should be enough

Comment: did that but still having the same number for both two courses. it should have different identifier

Comment: Your question is very unclear, it would be helpful if you added the expected output and what you have tried so far.  From the data you've supplied, I don't see how you can distinguish between the rows to determine a course identifier

Comment: Post the code you've tried that doesn't work. And it helps if you post what output you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the third variable, whatever it is, is your 'end state' the following works.  Probably not the easiest method but hopefully clear. I don't know if First/Last will actually help in this situation except for when the ID switches.

Idea is look for the V3=1 and then set a flag to 1. If the flag is 1, then the next record increments and resets the flag and the process is continued. Retain is used to hold the values of Flag and Course across the rows.

```
data have;
input ID $ v1-v3;
cards;
C 1 1 0
C 0 0 1
C 1 1 0
C 0 0 1
D 1 0 0
D 0 1 0
D 0 0 1
;
run;

data want;
set have;

BY ID;

retain flag 0 course;

if first.ID then do;
    Course=1;
    flag=0;
end;

if flag=1 then do;
    course=course+1;
    flag=0;
end;
else if v3=1 and flag=0 then flag=1;

run;

proc print;
run;
```